# eslint. Parsing error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, eslint, vue-typescript

well im using vue 3 + ts (composiiton api), and the issue is that is my eslint giving an error when i define interface

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import HeaderButton from './HeaderButton.vue'

interface Btns {
  iconName: string
  action: string
}

const btns = ref<Btns[]>([
  {
    iconName: 'asfasf',
    action: ''
  }
])
</script>
```

[image]

setting.json

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedLocales": {
    "ru": true
  },
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": ["source.fixAll.eslint"],
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.cjs

```
/* eslint-env node */
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution')

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/vue3-recommended', 'eslint:recommended', '@vue/eslint-config-prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest'
  }
}
```

.package.json

```
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.17.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.0.6",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.68.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.11"
```

vsCode ext:

- TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)
- Vue Language Features (Volar)
- Eslint

P.S. disabled @builtin typescript (**TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**) as recommended

tried to search over internet but nothing helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue you're facing with ESLint reporting a parsing error for the keyword "interface" is likely because ESLint doesn't recognize TypeScript syntax when used in the Vue 3  block. To fix this, you can configure ESLint to understand TypeScript syntax within Vue files.

- make sure you have the required ESLint and TypeScript packages installed: `npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`
- in your ESLint configuration (.eslintrc), add the parser and plugin configurations for TypeScript:

  ```
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extraFileExtensions": [".vue"],
    "ecmaVersion": 2021
  },
  "plugins": [
    "vue",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    // Your other ESLint rules
  }
  ```
- configure Vue files to be recognized as TypeScript files. In your `tsconfig.json` file:

  ```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue"  // Include .vue files
  ]
  ```
- after making these changes, restart your development server to ensure that ESLint recognizes TypeScript syntax within Vue files. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `.eslintrc.cjs` file, your ESLint is not configured for TypeScript.  Following the [documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/#quickstart) for typescript-eslint should hopefully correct the issue.

### Step 1. Installation

> npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin eslint typescript

### Step 2. Configuration

**.eslintrc.cjs**

```js
/* eslint-env node */
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution')

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-prettier',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest'
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint']
}
```